# Unable to plot marker using json and onPostExecute no response

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have been trying to plot marker using json but unable to plot it, `onPostExecute` i am unable to even show toast but the latlang is coming in individually and i am testing this using only 3-4 markers (json format) 
below is a json sample -

```
[{"name":"Thekha desi wine","address":"SR Complex, Naya Bans, Sector 15, Noida","latlang":["28.582122","77.313233"]},{"name":"Thekha desi wine","address":"SR Complex, Naya Bans, Sector 15, Noida","latlang":["28.582122","77.313233"]},{"name":"Thekha desi wine","address":"SR Complex, Naya Bans, Sector 15, Noida","latlang":["28.582122","77.313233"]}]
```

The `mapsActivity` code is:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {
public GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public void onMapSearch (View view) throws IOException {

    //hide button when button is pressed
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    //preview the entered address as an Tost in bar
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();

    //this will animate camera and zoom 12.0f
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f));

    //further address search codes
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    //if nothing will be entered in the edit-text will not show a toast rather than crashing of thekha app
    if (locationSearch.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Bitch please enter A Value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        //process of exception handling and finding location
        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            //if address is greater than one then these processes will happen

            if(addressList.size()>0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(location + " is Here- ")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                Toast.makeText(this, location+" is here, Zoom In or Zoom Out to make your Thekha Visible ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show(); //popup type to show entered data
            }
            else {
                //process where entered entry will not gonna find , this will gonna a toast to show popup

                Toast.makeText(this,"Entered Address Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

private class RetriveMarkerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    private Context context;
    private GoogleMap gMap;

    public RetriveMarkerTask(Context context, GoogleMap mMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.gMap = mMap;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "pre execute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... markerGetUrl) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        try {
            //connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(markerGetUrl[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //This will read the json data into string builder
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        String markersJson = new String(buff).trim();
        return markersJson;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String markers) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Post Execute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        LatLng dwarka = new LatLng(28.570317,77.32182);
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dwarka, 13));
        gMap.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("Wine Beer Liquor Shop, Sector 18, Noida")
                        .snippet("Sector 18, Near Centre Stage Mall, Noida")
                        .position(dwarka));
        /*
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(markers);
            for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                //create marker of each place in the json data
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String placeName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String placeAddress = jsonObject.getString("address");
                double latitude = jsonObject.getJSONArray("latlang").getDouble(0);
                double longitude = jsonObject.getJSONArray("latlang").getDouble(1);
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 13));
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(placeName)
                        .snippet(placeAddress)
                        .position(loc)
                );
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
    }
}

//OnReady map starts here when we can enter or add Marker to the map
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Map ready", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        String url =  new String("http://www.loofre.com/api-for-webservice/?debug=true&action=getLocations");
        RetriveMarkerTask markerTask = new RetriveMarkerTask(this, mMap);
        markerTask.execute(url);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Can not fetch data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //  int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    //tool bar and other tool related on map uiSettings
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Why you have two questions posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343995/android-studio-unable-to-plot-marker-using-json/39345189?noredirect=1#comment66054054_39345189

Comment: i am really in mess got no answers and that question have some different code , if you can please answer my question

Comment: @AmadYus Sir please tell me now how can i show marker now and why onPostExecute i am unable to show even toast ,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to get some base functionality without the OnMapReady()
try this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
public GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
mMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

try {
    String url =  new String("http://www.loofre.com/api-for-webservice/?debug=true&action=getLocations");
    RetriveMarkerTask markerTask = new RetriveMarkerTask(this, mMap);
    markerTask.execute(url);
}catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Can not fetch data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
        (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //  int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
//tool bar and other tool related on map uiSettings
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}

public void onMapSearch (View view) throws IOException {

//hide button when button is pressed
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

//preview the entered address as an Tost in bar
EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();

//this will animate camera and zoom 12.0f
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f));

//further address search codes
List<Address> addressList = null;

//if nothing will be entered in the edit-text will not show a toast rather than crashing of thekha app
if (locationSearch.getText().toString().equals("")){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Bitch please enter A Value",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
    //process of exception handling and finding location
    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        //if address is greater than one then these processes will happen

        if(addressList.size()>0) {
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(location + " is Here- ")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            Toast.makeText(this, location+" is here, Zoom In or Zoom Out to make your Thekha Visible ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show(); //popup type to show entered data
        }
        else {
            //process where entered entry will not gonna find , this will gonna a toast to show popup

            Toast.makeText(this,"Entered Address Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}

private class RetriveMarkerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
private Context context;
private GoogleMap gMap;

public RetriveMarkerTask(Context context, GoogleMap mMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.gMap = mMap;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){
    Toast.makeText(context, "pre execute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

protected String doInBackground(String... markerGetUrl) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    int read;
    char[] buff = new char[1024];
    try {
        //connect to the web service
        URL url = new URL(markerGetUrl[0]);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //This will read the json data into string builder
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            json.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    String markersJson = new String(buff).trim();
    return markersJson;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String markers) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Post Execute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    LatLng dwarka = new LatLng(28.570317,77.32182);
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dwarka, 13));
    gMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("Wine Beer Liquor Shop, Sector 18, Noida")
                    .snippet("Sector 18, Near Centre Stage Mall, Noida")
                    .position(dwarka));

}
}

}
```

Comment: getMap(); and (this); shows error , ask me to add onMapReady on this and getMap shows that can not resolve method

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

to

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.safety_map));
```

I expected, it will work perfectly. Best of luck!